# Change the homepage in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm using prestashop 1.5.2

I would like to change my homepage. 
Actually it's `index.php` but I would like to set it to `index.php?id_category=12`.
Where can I disable the homepage and specify the new one?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That would be the same file... you just have a variable appended to the URL. You just need to change the links that point to it to point to the new URL instead of thew old one.

Comment: I know that's the same file. But if the user goes to my-website.com/index.php through the url bar. I will not be redirected on my-website.com/index.php?id_category=12

Comment: From your comment, it sounds like you're now talking about redirecting index.php to index.php?id_category=12. It probably would have made more sense if that was actually in your question. Just use htaccess or php to do a redirect.

Comment: Yep, I thought it was possible to specify it in PS admin, but I will do a redirection it's easier. ;)